# Missing results when filtering messages by SentDateTime using Outlook REST API v2.0

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to get all messages since 2017-06-15T18:24:13Z.

(I'm using 5-result pages and only selecting SentDateTime to simplify this case. This issue also happens when selecting more fields and a larger page size)

Requesting the total number of messages:

```
>>> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/$count?$filter=SentDateTime+ge+2017-06-15T18:24:13Z&select=SentDateTime&$top=5

3988
```

Now fetching the messages:

```
>>> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/?$filter=SentDateTime+ge+2017-06-15T18:24:13Z&select=SentDateTime&$top=5

{
  "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Messages(SentDateTime)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAAAHSJlCAAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMlWeb\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAAAHSJlCAAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-15T18:27:24Z"
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCpAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdlVnAAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSF+rD\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCpAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdlVnAAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-15T18:37:29Z"
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAAAHSJiQAAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSGAe8\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAAAHSJiQAAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-15T19:12:22Z"
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCpAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdlVpAAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSF+rE\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCpAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdlVpAAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-15T19:15:58Z"
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl74AAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSGAe9\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl74AAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-15T19:20:05Z"
    }
  ],
  "@odata.nextLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/?%24filter=sentdatetime+ge+2017-06-15T18%3a24%3a13Z&%24select=SentDateTime&%24top=5&%24skip=5"
}
```

Requesting the next page:

```
>>> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/?$filter=sentdatetime+ge+2017-06-15T18:24:13Z&$select=SentDateTime&$top=5&$skip=5

{
  "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Messages(SentDateTime)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl73AAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSGAe+\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl73AAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-15T19:24:13Z"
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl70AAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSGAe/\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl70AAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-15T20:19:27Z"
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCpAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdlVtAAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSF+rF\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCpAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdlVtAAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-15T20:20:12Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

The second response doesn't contain a nextLink, meanning there are only 8 results and the last message was sent at 2017-06-15T20:20:12Z.

However, when querying for the following day:

```
>>> https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/?$filter=SentDateTime+ge+2017-06-16T00:00:00Z&select=SentDateTime&$top=5

{
  "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/$metadata#Me/Messages(SentDateTime)",
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl8dAAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSGAfR\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl8dAAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-16T00:52:10Z"
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl8cAAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSGAfS\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl8cAAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-16T01:37:09Z"
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl8ZAAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSGAfT\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl8ZAAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-16T02:59:38Z"
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl8VAAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSGAfU\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl8VAAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-16T03:03:25Z"
    },
    {
      "@odata.id": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('d2fe4aac-1eae-4d14-9893-4f96f42ae46b@487bfe01-8734-4c88-9424-11fa0c5d445e')/Messages('AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl8UAAA=')",
      "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABSGAfV\"",
      "Id": "AAMkADU3ZDE1ZGJiLTg4ZmUtNGVlYy1hYzE4LWMyNjE1NzY4YWUzYQBGAAAAAABGFgzFsCOpRISdXXbGh88oBwA0lgq1qqsaRYyJVwoDR59-AAAvWYCsAADjWpP0ATh5SI1bqWxqzWOKAABMdl8UAAA=",
      "SentDateTime": "2017-06-16T03:20:12Z"
    }
  ],
  "@odata.nextLink": "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/?%24filter=SentDateTime+ge+2017-06-16T00%3a00%3a00Z&%24select=SentDateTime&%24top=5&%24skip=5"
}
```

Meaning there are indeed more messages than the 8 returned by the original request.

I tried modifying the request by starting from a different SentDateTime value, but it keeps stopping at this last message. The same issue happens with different mailboxes on different dates.

Any clue on how to approach this?

**EDIT**
As a temporary fix, I'm looping through all the folders (using /me/mailFolders) and fetching them one at time using the same filter. This seems to work in lieu of a proper solution

Comment: Hmm. To be clear, are you actually copying and using the value of `@odata.nextLink`, or are you computing the `$skip` yourself?

Comment: Copying and using the exact value, never computing it myself

Comment: Ok. I can't reproduce this behavior, so the best thing might be to get some Fiddler traces of your repro and send them to me offline. If you can't get traces, if you can at least get full response headers correlated with request URLs that would be helpful.

Comment: @JasonJohnston well this is embarrassing, I can't reproduce this either . Can swear this was an issue a month ago. Will let you know if I encounter this again. Thanks for the quick turnarount, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to query data from sentItems folder?

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/mailFolders/SentItems/messages/?$filter=SentDateTime+ge+2017-06-15T18:24:13Z&select=SentDateTime&$top=5

Comment: I'm looking for all the messages in the mailbox - whether they were sent or recieved by the user - regardless of the folder they're at.
Is there a better way to do that?